# cmp in bash gives wrong result

Tags: cmp

I execute `cmp` in two files and despite are the same, I get

`file1 file2.csv differ: char 1, line 1`

Why this might happen?

Comment: One file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), the other doesn't?

Comment: How can I find out? Or maybe ignoring?

Comment: try cat file1 | od -x and compare the hex dumps - look for a BOM like Biffen suggested

Comment: Run `od -c file1 | head -1` and `od -c file2.csv | head -1` and add the results to the test of your question.

Comment: @polegar `file file1 file2.csv` would tell you (IIRC).